# The sum of differences of array elements from each other

Tags: c

That is my code. But the output is wrong. My expected output is:

input: `1 2 3`
output: `3 2 3`;
but the actual output is `2 1 0` on my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int n; // create a variables to decide how many number that they want to store on array
    int position[10];
    int sumdiffs[10];
    printf("How many number you want to enter here: ?\n"); // let users enter how much number
    scanf("%d", &n);
    // accept users number
    for (int m = 0; m < n; m++) {
        printf("Please enter number %d:", m + 1);
        scanf("%d", &position[m]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            sumdiffs[i] = abs(position[i] - position[j]);
        } 

        printf("%d\n", sumdiffs[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

That is my test.

```
How many number you want to enter here: ?
3
Please enter number 1:1
Please enter number 2:2
Please enter number 3:3
2
1
0
```

Comment: How is this different from [Finding the sum of differences of array elements from each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72195049/finding-the-sum-of-differences-of-array-elements-from-each-other) — a question you asked a couple of hours ago?  You might do best deleting your previous question if this one is better.

Comment: @ Jonathan Leffler i finish the nested loop here, but I did not get the correct answer.

Comment: Why do you think you should get `{3,2,3}` ?

Comment: You should ensure that `sumdiffs` is zeroed and use addition in `sumdiffs[i] = abs(position[i] - position[j]);`.

Comment: @ Vulpo There is a nested loop, the element of array will be calculated with other elements, the absolute difference would add together and store on sumdiffs

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler Thanks for your help, I am not zeroed the sumdiffs, that why the number looks wrong when i use addition.

Comment: Make sure `sumdiffs` is initially filled with zeros, then change the innermost line of your nested loop to be `sumdiffs[i] += abs(position[i] - position[j]);`

Answer (score 0):

You are not computing the sum of differences, you only store each difference so the array `sumdiffs` contains the last difference.

Note also that your code has undefined behavior for `n` greater than `10` because you access the arrays beyond their boundaries.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int n;
    printf("How many numbers you want to enter here?\n");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n <= 0)
        return 1;
    // arrays defined with the correct size (hopefully not too large)
    int position[n];
    int sumdiffs[n];
    // read the numbers from the user
    for (int m = 0; m < n; m++) {
        printf("Please enter number %d: ", m + 1);
        if (scanf("%d", &position[m]) != 1)
            return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sumdiffs[i] = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            sumdiffs[i] += abs(position[i] - position[j]);
        } 
        printf("%d\n", sumdiffs[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, clear the accumulated sums:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    sumdiffs[i] = 0;
```

Then, just change

```
sumdiffs[i] = abs(position[i] - position[j]);
```

into

```
sumdiffs[i] += abs(position[i] - position[j]);
```

to accumulate the differences.